# Inserting mysql values directly into pdf using x,y coordinates.

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

Any suggestions for a resource to insert database values directly into pdf using x,y coordinates, preferably in php? I have a form that needs to be populated with information contained in a database. The form cannot be altered in any way.

a google search gave me this: http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/
and i was also able to find TCPDF. Will these work? Are there better solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience i would like to suggest you to try [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)
library. It provides goods features as well as examples for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If you have a PDF with a form inside, and you are trying to fill the form with data and save the PDF with the filled forms, try this here:

http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/

its pretty self-explanatory.

On the other hand, if you try to create a new PDF file, I can also recommend the fpdf library.

As an added hint: I often came to the conclusion that it can be also very easy to make a HTML file, add the CSS for page breaks and then convert that into PDF at the client computer with a print-to-PDF function. It saves you from bending your output to fit the limitations of PDF libraries.